# Getting some red messages after running the project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have written only 2 lines of code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/24c6O.png

And getting Passed as result. But also seeing the red info message.
Can anyone help to remove this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/39hPh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A93Ej.png

I uninstall the eclipse and re-install. Uninstall TestNg version.